# Understanding a browser rendering "quirk"

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRG6B/).

**Quick info:**

- The div is 500px wide
- The image inside it is centered with css (margin: 0 auto)
- The image has an anchor tag wrapper around it (no css)

**Problem:**
If you inspect the anchor tag (firebug or other inspector), it shows as the same width and height as the image, which to me is correct, BUT the full div is clickable.

**Questions:**

- Is firebug showing the wrong size of the anchor tag?
- Are the browsers wrong? (I assume not)
- What's going on? :)

Comment: Anchor shows 500px wide here... (Chromium 15, Ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Firebug isn't. Though, I want to know why? Why does the auto margin of the image widen the anchor when the anchor is inline itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because the <img> is styled with `display:block`. That means that the <img> *element* (!) (as opposed to the graphic image itself) will expand to fill whatever width is allocated to it. Note that when you remove `display:block` setting, the clickable area falls back to the expanse of the image, as expected.

The question then becomes: How do you center the linked image while limiting the clickable area to the image? One way is:

```
div { width: 500px; text-align:center; }
```

Comment: Seems logical enough, but Firebug made me confused. Could be a feature request :)

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag as around the image.  The image has a margin. auto isn't 0 here, it's the difference between 500 and the width of the image / 2.

If you would like to not include the margin, wrap the image and anchor in a div, then position that with margin:0 auto;